# Get random value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that outputs the following:

```
Array ( [roi_data] => Array (
    [0] => Array ( [title] => Test ROI )
    [1] => Array ( [title] => Another ROI ) 
))
```

I'd like to combine all the keys with title into one array and then echo a random value out of it.

I have tried using `array_rand()` but I just get the word `Array` to appear.

Comment: Please format your output properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a multidimensional array. When you call `array_rand`, you're getting back a random element from the first tier of arrays -- this element would be an array itself.

```
Array (
    [roi_data] => Array (          <-- there is only one element in the top level
        [0] => Array (               <-- there are two elements in this level
            [title] => Test ROI        <-- there is only one element in this level
        ), 
        [1] => Array (
            [title] => Another ROI 
        )
    )
)
```

So, if you wanted a random element from the `roi_data` level, you'd have to specify that:

```
$key = array_rand($myArray['roi_data']);
$item = $myArray['roi_data'][$key];
echo $item['title'];
```

**Documentation**

- `array_rand` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php
- PHP Arrays - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
- Understanding multidimensional arrays - http://webcheatsheet.com/php/multidimensional_arrays.php

Answer (score 6):

You have a nested array, so you'll need:

```
$key = array_rand( $array['roi_data']);
echo $array['roi_data'][$key]['title'];
```

Comment: An answer that explains nothing, and gives no links to explanations is not useful. It's the whole *give a man a fish, feed him for a day. teach him how to fish, feed him for life* bit. Just putting the code that he needs to do it is not constructive for anyone (OP or future needs)...

Comment: Since the OP already knew about `array_rand()`, the error is the misconception of a nested array, which I probably could've explained better. Still, the code is self explanatory (IMO), and the OP or anybody else with a similar problem should be able to discern what's happening.